# How do I silence this 'Result of 'WebView' initializer is unused' warning and navigate to WebView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I have links embedded in text I'm trying to navigate to a WebView using the OpenURLAction by swift. I've created a view that takes a url and displays it. But I'm running into this error. When I assign `_ =` Its not transitioning to the WebView [image]

```
 public var body: some View {
....
                    Group {
                        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                            Text(.init(model.blockText()))
                                .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction(handler: { url in
                                    WebView(url: url)
                                    return .handled
                                }))
                               
                        } else {
                            Text(.init(model.blockText()))
                        }
                    }
....
}
```

Comment: The `handler` closure is where you put executable code, not views like `WebView`. Instead try making a new `@State var url: URL?` and do `self.url = url`. Then somewhere in your `ContentView` you can show the url, with `if let url = self.url { WebView(url: url) }`

Comment: The  **if let url = self.url { WebView(url: url)** doesn't get executed

Comment: This needs a [mre] to give a concrete answer. @aheze's suggestion is almost certainly on the right track, but if you're having trouble implementing it, you should provide all of the code necessary to give a full answer.